# How replace string in wordpress post title using function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, string, replace, title

I want to replace dash char '-' in post title with `function.php` but I can not do it.

it's my code:

```
function the_breadcrumb()
{
    if (is_single()) 
    {
        str_replace(" - ", $strReplaceWith, get_the_title());
    }
}
```

This code does not work because `wordpress` automatically replace '-' with '–', also I used this code (below) but it does not worked too.

```
function the_breadcrumb()
{
    if (is_single()) 
    {
        str_replace(" – ", $strReplaceWith, get_the_title());
    }
}
```

I try first code on another document (`test.php`) it worked but I can not use this code in `function.php`

Sorry, I can't speak English very well.

Comment: You can use either regex or an array of values to search and replace..the tricky part about trying to replace them in `the_title()` is you have to accommodate all the permutations of what a user can put in the `title` field. Your example is searching for `" – "` meaning if there's no ` ` (space) on either side (or if there's only a space on one side) of the hyphen then it won't replace anything. Your best bet is to either create a regex pattern to use as your needle in str_replace or an array of all the various options, or simply use `array('-', '–')`

Answer (score -1):

Try to apply wordpress filter hooks. Remove get_the_title() change to the_title(). https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title.

Comment: [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) echoes the title.